# Consulta entre dos fecha con hora Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Hola necesito hacer una consulta entre dos fecha con hora

```
$data = Modelo::whereBetween('created_at', ['2018/11/10 12:00', '2018/11/11 10:30'])
->get();
```

Pero al hacer esta consulta me trae todos los resultados entre las fechas sin tomar en cuenta las horas.

Las fechas se guardan automáticamente con Eloquent

Y aparte hago lo siguiente para formatear las fechas que voy a buscar:

```
Carbon::now()->parse($date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: En qué formato tienes guardadas las fechas con horas? Por qué así como lo pones no es válido para un datetime

Comment: LA fecha las guarda automáticamente eloquent cuando guardo un registro

Comment: Entendido, en cuanto tenga Acceso a una pc te respondo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder hacer una búsqueda entre 2 fechas, dentro de `Laravel` debes proceder del modo siguiente:

Si el campo de tu base de datos es de tipo `DATETIME` la estructura de tu consulta debe ser del modo siguiente:

```
$data = Modelo::whereBetween('created_at', ['2018/11/10 12:00:00', '2018/11/11 10:30:00'])->get();
```

O también

```
$data = Modelo::whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-11-10 12:00', '2018-11-11 10:30'])
->get();
```

Debes tener presente que para que el calculo se haga como lo requieres; tu campo debe tener esta estructura:

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` -> `2018-11-12 12:52:12`

Si por ejemplo vas a ocupar **Carbon**

Puede quedar de este modo:

```
$fechaFormateada = Carbon::now();
$data = User::whereBetween('created_at', ['2018-11-24 15:49:02', $fechaFormateada])  
                                                                            ->get();
return $data;
```

**¿Qué hay con la propiedad fechaFormateada?**

Si haces esto:

`var_dump($fechaFormateada);`

Vas a obtener como resultado lo siguiente

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#485 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-11-28 00:53:33.425487" 
                                ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> 
                                 string(3) "UTC" }
```

Que como puedes ver si incluye los segundos; para respetar el formato de datos que requiere el campo `DATETIME`

Comment: Gracias efectivamente solo era el formato de la fecha.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es colocar dos inputs de esta manera en tu html

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="desde">
<input type="datetime-local" name="hasta">
```

el atributo datetime-local te tomara tanto la fecha como la hora ya que es lo que necesitas
y en tu query puedes usarlo de esta manera

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->desde, $request->hasta])
```

ojo en tu controlador debes pasarle request de esta forma

```
public function myController(Request $request)
{
     //aqui ira tu consulta (query) para generar lo que deseas
}
```

espero haberte ayudado y resuelto tu pregunta